# can not load luafilesystem in lua

Tags: lua, luafilesystem

when i load lfs module in lua file, i got the error message:

```
error loading module 'lfs' from file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/lfs.so':
/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/lfs.so:1: unexpected symbol near 'char(127)'
```

here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
package.path = package.path .. ";/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/?.so"
require"lfs"
```

if i execute the code in lua console, it succeed;
if i copy the lfs.so file to the same directory as the lua file, i succeed too.
i had googled,but can't find a solution.

Comment: use instead `package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/?.so"`

Comment: @hjpotter92 it works, thank you! btw, do you knew how to close the question on stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading a C library. For C library packages, the path to be used should be `package.cpath`.

> `package.path` (for modules written in Lua) and `package.cpath` (for
>   modules written in C) are the places where Lua looks for modules. They
>   are semicolon-separated lists, and each entry can have a `?` in it
>   that's replaced with the module name.
>
> [(source)](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial)